# Not Returning from B2C Login

Tags: xamarin, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c) against my tenant but after I sign-in, I'm not returning to my Android Xamarin app.

I've updated the [constants.cs file](https://github.com/spottedmahn/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/my-tenant/WebServices/AzureADB2CAuth/ADB2CAuthorization/Constants.cs) w/ my values:

```cs
// set your tenant name, for example "contoso123tenant"
static readonly string tenantName = "spottedmahnb2c";

// set your tenant id, for example: "contoso123tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
static readonly string tenantId = "spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com";

// set your client/application id, for example: aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee"
static readonly string clientId = "3f748dfd-91ed-4b50-a41c-6ca5242a2043";

// set your sign up/in policy name, for example: "B2C_1_signupsignin"
static readonly string policySignin = "B2C_1_Mobile";
```

---

Using the [connected devices](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-debugging-webview/) in chrome dev tools I've been able to see a little bit about what is failing:

In the console I see:

> Navigation is unreachable: msal3f748dfd-91ed-4b50-a41c-6ca5242a2043://auth/?state=36ffbf5e-1758-409d-a365-500a7799af0e1f5c213c-4da9-469d-bdbc-b33eeed61043&code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInppcCI6IkRlZmxhdGUiLCJzZXIiOiIxLjAifQ..DN_f7iZU72KDnWTF.WTGU6pLKVNt7LU6hYoeb-Rm5G75DPbsV06TFs6UU4S2k2NJo3BvRatWN_pIsWNoY54dLVQVaEY3OT5R1YDDiUsQHvnLeAfe7JacoUrSCRPjGiowa_pLJmZvA3gzquKZ0C25nND2SXzc2JswdXgzdeXS6XIO38o4qKuY_T7lp0vQjdxtbTD4VGrS2on53RuVZ8owyZK5Um1wOetom_7vhIXcRPIMhiRYVEsFvtX5KcytvJY4BEiUN_2rvlGkOK8qhxcDMBNJueWmCeAi5kSKMHic7318JFpsngRPF253XlorFM6VOG3qkOFRUNQMXRegngfyOVMRmu6EnBOjX8md9YOjlPyGSAYSWuFH3FoXIS1dEyD31P8GeuhQUMzu1rcmgMesGDFiSmt-Ej3YKw374pWugRD8HGSRkL4XDJlqRktQ3c9k8-gTxj5zNnvSCRhTxbY47KWuz-pEmFYaJ9UNddR1KJ6VRKe3ksdL36GfLXA_sexF70gjCTCry3vbIqRTcvzzGvQPVSkzRn24FeRwvlsCq_R4PUqVcRgffoU_SD5KUKB0p24c1y5qAOiPaygFl6JvLcG-LYdF1XLITfwN2BsGw6K0qFzeo4Q.TAMYJQduSu1QlZa-u2T4_A

In the network tab I see:

[image: confirmed screenshot from Xamarin browser]

[image: call stack of canceled request]

---

I've tried my [sign-up/sign-in policy](https://spottedmahnb2c.b2clogin.com/spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_Mobile&client_id=3f748dfd-91ed-4b50-a41c-6ca5242a2043&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=msal3f748dfd-91ed-4b50-a41c-6ca5242a2043%3A%2F%2Fauth&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login) via the browser and it appears to be "working".  My B2C app is configured for a native/mobile app so it doesn't completely work but I'm not failing on the `confirmed` request like I am in the mobile app.

[image: confirmed screenshot in browser]

[image: auth request url screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed a step in the guide: [Android Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c#android).  I needed to fill out the URI scheme: `<data android:scheme="INSERT_URI_SCHEME_HERE" android:host="auth" />` in *AndroidManifest.xml*

```xml
<data android:scheme="msal3f748dfd-91ed-4b50-a41c-6ca5242a2043" android:host="auth" />
```

Thanks to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native#optional-step-6b-configure-the-android-project-with-your-apps-return-uri) I was able to figure out the format.